# Positive definite function zoo

Tags: unitary-representations, harmonic-analysis, big-list

I've asked the following question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57315) but there has been no response so I'll ask it again here:

A positive definite function $\varphi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ on a group $G$ is a function that arises as a "diagonal" coefficient of a unitary representation of $G$.

For a definition and discussion of positive definite function see [here](http://eom.springer.de/P/p073890.htm).

I've often wished I had a collection of diverse examples of positive definite functions on groups, for the purpose of testing various conjectures. I hope the diverse experience of the participants of this forum can help me collect a list of such examples.

To clarify what I'd like to see:

> What is an example of a positive
>   definite function on a group $G$ that
>   is not easily seen to be a coefficient
>   of a unitary representation of $G$?
>   What are some positive definite
>   functions that arise in contexts
>   sufficiently removed from studying the
>   coefficients of unitary
>   representations?

Also, the weirder the group $G$ the better. I'd like a collection of quirky beasts...

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function.

Answer (score 7):

For me, often positive-definite functions arise as kernel functions in [*machine learning*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)

A small list can be found [at this link](http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning.html)

Also, I would also add one of the classic books on this subject:

[Harmonic analysis on semigroups](http://books.google.com/books?id=zz2DQgAACAAJ&dq=harmonic+analysis+semigroups&hl=en&ei=X4pSTqyHCI7UiAKy-5GRAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA) by Christian Berg, Jens Peter Reus Christensen, Paul Ressel.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for, Suvrit. This connection with machine learning is quite new to me!

Answer (score 6):

I guess the example below provides one answer to your first question.

A famous positive-definite function** is the one in the *Bessis-Moussa-Villani* conjecture:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices. Then the function
$$\phi(t) = \mbox{trace}(e^{A+i t B}),$$
is a positive-definite function.

** Conjectured to be positive-definite, though apparently it has been proved very recently; however, until that has been verified independently, I will adhere to the safety of the word "conjecture"

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you are already aware of this, but I thought I'd mention it for other interested google-enabled readers.

1. [Infinitely divisible distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility) are one place where positive-definite functions come up (Lévy processes, Lévy-Khintchine formula, etc., are also relevant keywords)
2. [Infinite divisibility in Free Probability](http://www.springerlink.com/index/p4w6m26481406070.pdf) is another related place.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.